# Mysql Connection could not established long run process

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I am using a MySQL database and Java. I am inserting data continuously without closing the connection. The problem is that the connection holds the MySQL server so that it hangs. It also affects my web application. The connection could not be established. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please share some existing code !!!

Comment: shows your code or any error you having issues.

Comment: And don't forget the stack trace!

Comment: Do commit after each insert  ... so connection don't have opened transition  ...